# How to setup string return function in header file and use that function in another class or .pp

Tags: c++

While I was practicing object oriented in c++ I encounter issue with declaration of string return function in Header file and use that function in another class or .cpp.

For example,

File.h

```
#ifndef File_H
#define File_H
#include <string>
class File
{
private:
public:
    string Read_File(string line);
    void Open_files();
};

#endif
#pragma once
```

File.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "File.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

string Read_File(string userInput) {
    userInput = "data.txt";
    ifstream myfile(userInput);
    string line;
    string result = "B";
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        if (result == line) {
            return line + "\n";
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

.txt file

```
A
B
C
```

I am getting error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0147   declaration is incompatible with "<error-type> File::test(<error-type> t)" (declared at line 8 of "C:\Users\t\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\File.h") ConsoleApplication2 C:\Users\t\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\File.cpp    65
```

Comment: It should be `std::string` everywhere. It should also be `std::ifstream` and `std::getline`.

Comment: The error mentions `<error-type> File::test(<error-type> t)` but you haven't shown `File::test` in your code. Neither in the class definition nor in the implementation part. Show the actual code that gives that error.

Answer (score 1):

Given your class definition

```
class File
{
   public:
      string Read_File(string line);
 };
```

you need to make sure a member function definition is correctly attributed to the class type `File`:

```
string File::Read_File(string userInput) {
    // ^^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

Otherwise, the compiler treats `Read_File` as free function. This free function cannot access any members of `File`, and the linker can't find a definition for the member function `File::Read_File`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the standard namespace: `std` whit every `string` as `std::string`.

Comment: That's should be a comment and doesn't completely solve the problem.